# vsftpd config problem

Tags: networking, server, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

i've setup a ftp server for my webdev class

i can login on local network, using internet sharing of my phone ( to test remote access ) , with a different user, using another computer ...
but no one else execpt myself can access it !! cant figure out why ...

here's filezilla log:

```
Statut :    Connexion TLS établie.
Commande :    USER eric
Réponse :    331 Please specify the password.
Commande :    PASS **
Erreur :    Erreur GnuTLS -15 dans gnutls_record_recv: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
Erreur :    Impossible de lire depuis le socket : ECONNABORTED - Connexion annulée
Erreur :    Impossible d'établir une connexion au serveur[/code]
```

vsftpd.conf:

```
listen=YES
listen_port=210
listen_ipv6=NO
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=002
chmod_enable=YES
file_open_mode=0774
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
local_root=/var/www/webdev/$USER
user_sub_token=$USER
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/root/.acme.sh/xxx.xxx.org/xxx.xxx.org.cer
rsa_private_key_file=/root/.acme.sh/xxx.xxx.org/xxx.xxx.org.key
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
pasv_enable=Yes
pasv_min_port=10000
pasv_max_port=10100
pasv_addr_resolve=YES
pasv_address=xxx.xxx.org
pasv_promiscuous=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
syslog_enable=YES
```

forwarded ports of my router:

[ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shFxh.png)

folders permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 18 08:06 eric
```

users groups:

```
lilbuh@webdev:/var/www/webdev$ groups eric
eric : eric www-data
```

can't understand... help please :)

Comment: What OS & release?   Some of your paths look unusual..

Comment: ubuntu server 20.04.01 LTS

Answer (score 1):

FIXED !! thanks to jpoc on [ubuntu-fr.org](https://www.ubuntu-fr.org/)

vsftpd checks for the user's home dir even if it's not navigating it...
if not created (the user never logged in via ssh) the home dir is not created and vsftpd closes the connection

a simple

sudo mkhomedir_helper

fixes the issue :)